# Need to be able to specify IP address of IMAP server on local network

Tags: ssl, imap

I have an IMAP server that can be accessed from a public address that is behind a firewall.  It has correct SSL certificates for the public name.  It is easy to test this server from the private network using "openssl s_client -crlf -connect 192.168.x.x:993 -servername imap.example.com" which validates the certificate agains servername rather than the local address. I realize a host table entry pointing to the private address would do the same but causes problems in other areas.  Does anyone know if there is a connection string in an IMAP client or php imap_open for that matter so that I could specify a private address and a servername so that the cert would validate correctly?

Comment: Could you just forget about the hostname and trust a self-signed cert for `CN=192.168.x.x` on the client?

Comment: other related topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback